# Can't connect to Mac Build Host -- Error loading xcode information

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

As the subject leads into, I am having trouble connecting to my mac build host. It was working earlier in the week (and I think there was an update). I can't run an iOS app from Xamarin studio either (I think it has something to do with Xamarin connecting to Xcode as when I try to run from Xamarin studio I get a message saying the code hasn't been built yet)

I have tried re-installing xamarin.ios as well as xcode.

When I run `telnet localhost 5000` I receive the following message (hinting that the problem is with xcode)

```
Error: Error loading Xcode information for prefix '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'
Exception: Exception type: System.FormatException
Input string was not in the correct format at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at MonoTouch.Tools.Frameworks.AppleSdkSettings.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
System.ApplicationException: Apple SDK developer root not specified.
at MonoTouch.Tools.Frameworks.MonoTouchFrameworks.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mtb.Application.MainClass.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mtb.Application.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Exception: Exception type: System.ApplicationException
Apple SDK developer root not specified.
at MonoTouch.Tools.Frameworks.MonoTouchFrameworks.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mtb.Application.MainClass.Init () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Mtb.Application.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Error: Unknown error occurred.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks as if there is a breaking change in the update of xcode -- see here for the workaround for the time being -- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/10837/#Comment_10837

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`XCode` 4.6.2 doesn't work (yet) with Xamarin Studio. Reinstall 4.6.1 from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

That's how I solved the same issue here

Comment: Just did the same on my my Mac and can confirm that this solves the problem :)